# What's the status of files when using a git reset --mixed HEAD~1?

Tags: git, git-reset

For example, if I create a file.txt and add some contents to it and then I commit this change to history. And what's the status of file.txt when using a git reset --mixed HEAD~1? I use the `git status` to check the status and below is the output:

```
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   file.txt

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

My question is, is this file.txt still in the index(staged)? If yes, why cannot I use `git commit` to commit the change?

Comment: It looks like you can add it and commit it above.. Is your question why it isn't staged?

Comment: Aren't all the files in the index staged (in other words, one can directly commit the changes without doing a git add)?

Comment: The file isn't in the index (staging area) above. It needs to be added in order to include the modification in a commit

Comment: With --mixed the index is reset to how it was in HEAD~1.  If you wanted it to remain staged you need to have used --soft.

Comment: @Martin if it's not in the index, what's the status of it? Modified? But it's not the same with the file.txt in the working directory. And if I git checkout file.txt, it will override the file.txt in the working directory. I am confused about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

file.txt has been modified compared to the commit you have checked out. The modifications are only present in the working directory. In order to commit them you need to add file.txt to the staging area (or index, same thing) and commit.

To discard the modification, you can checkout the file, meaning its' content will be synchronized with the content of the file in the commit you checkout.